# Factorization of $a^{dq+r}-1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, factoring

So I'm having trouble with factorizing:

$$a^{dq+r} - 1$$.

I'm aware that $a^n - 1$ factorizes to $(a - 1)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}+\ldots +a+1)$.

So I assume that the correct answer must be $(a^{dq}-1)(a^{dq+r-1} +\ldots +a^{dq}+1)$.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure what you want to get. You already know $a^n-1 = (a-1)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\cdots+a+1)$. This gives you a factorization of $a^{dq+r}-1$ by substituting $dq+r$ for $n$. It isn't immediately clear to me that there is another "nice" factorization. But your factorization doesn't work as the highest degree term is $a^{2dq+r-1}\ne a^{dq+r}$ (assuming $dq\ne 1$ of course).

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I'm actually trying to solve another problem but this seems like it won't help me.

Perhaps if I ask the real question of proving that:
$a^{qd} - 1$ divides $a^{qd+r} - 1$

Comment: This certainly doesn't happen though, if for any $d,q,r$ we had $a^{dq}-1\mid a^{dq+r}-1$, then if we let $q=1$, we would have $a^d-1\mid a^{d+r}-1$ for any $r$, which is certainly not true. E.g $x^2-1 \nmid x^{2+1}-1$.